# Application menu only on maximised windows?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I know that there is a way to disable global menu.  I don't quite want this as I quite like (at least one thing about) global menu.  I would like to know if there is a way of disabling global menu for non-maximised windows.

Thus I ask: is this possible and if so, how is it done?

To me, the menu bar/global menu should be visually a part of the window since it is a part of the program and the window is meant to encapsulate the program.

Global menu is only visually a part of a window when the window is maximised and merged with the top bar.  I don't like bits of my windows floating all around the screen.  You wouldn't drive a car when the driver's seat is on the roof of your house.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you, and [there's a quick FIX](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aCpCeL3nirc8J%3awww.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html):

```
echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=" | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
```

BTW, there's a [BUG submited to Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/701294) about this.

Comment: The main bug is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/682788 IMHO

Answer (score 0):

With 14.04 go to "System parameters"/"Appearance"/"Behavior" than switch "Show the menus for a window" to "In the window's title bar".

The menus will then appear when hovering a non-maximized window's title bar.